# Файлы, запись максимального значения

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

> Есть  файл f, компоненты которого являются целыми числами. Записать в файл g наибольшее значение первых ста компонент файла f, затем - следующих ста компонент и т.д. Если в последней группе окажется менее
>   ста компонент, то последняя компонента файла g должна быть равна наибольшей из компонент файла f, образующих последнюю (неполную) группу.

Мой код

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        StreamReader ^rd = File::OpenText("f.txt");
        rd->Close();
        StreamWriter^ wr1 = File::CreateText("f.txt");
        StreamWriter^ wr = File::CreateText("g.txt");

        wr1->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
        wr1->Close();
        String^ str;
        int cnt = 0, max = 0, v;

        while (true)
        {
            StreamReader ^rd = File::OpenText("f.txt");
            str = rd->ReadLine();


            // Или в конце или каждые 100 элементов пишем результат
            if ((str == nullptr) | (cnt >= 100))
            {
                wr->WriteLine(max);
                cnt = 0;

                if (str == nullptr)
                    break;
            }

            v = Convert::ToInt64(str);
            if ((cnt == 0) | (v > max))
                max = v;
            textBox3->Text = Convert::ToString(max);

            cnt++;
        }

        wr->Close();
        rd->Close();
             }
```

[image: Winform]

Ввожу числа в первый textBox1, хочу записать их в файл f, При нажатии на кнопку работать, выскакивает ошибка

System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Ругается на строчку

```
v = Convert::ToInt64(str);
```

Вопрос: Почему выходит эта ошибка и как ее исправить

Comment: Маи глоза... Столько бреда в коде, руки опускаются... Для начала, удалите первые две строки: зачем открывать файл и тут же закрывать? Главная ошибка: вместо оператора `|` используйте `||`. Надеюсь, сами найдёте, чем они отличаются.

Comment: Я хотел открыть файл и для записи и для чтения, поэтому решил вот так написать)

Comment: Вопрос решён? Дайте отклик.

Comment: Да, вопрос решен, ошибка устранена, задал вопрос по этой задаче в другой теме